# Mysql - Access column from grandparent's joined table in WHERE in subquery inside parent's FROM

Tags: mysql

Inside a `WHERE` inside a subquery inside a `FROM` inside another subquery inside a `SELECT` that's joined to another table, I need to access a column from that joined table.

edited to add more complete example:

```
SELECT
  field_one,
  field_two,
  field_three,
  field_one-field_three AS field_five,
  field_six
FROM (
  SELECT
    IFNULL(
      (
        SELECT
          SUM(us.field_seven) AS field_one
        FROM
          table_one us
        WHERE
          us.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
      AND
      us.created >= (
        SELECT 
          IF(
            selected_date IS NULL,
            MIN(created),
            selected_date
          )
        FROM (
          SELECT
            IF(
              latest_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL rtt.relevant_field_two DAY),
              CURDATE(),
              MAX(prevdate)
            ) AS selected_date,
            created
          FROM (
            SELECT
              created,
              @calc_prevdate as prevdate,
              DATEDIFF(@calc_prevdate, created) AS diff,
              @calc_prevdate := created
            FROM (
              SELECT
                sto.created
              FROM
                table_one sto
              WHERE
                sto.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              UNION ALL
              SELECT
                stt.created
              FROM
                table_two stt
              WHERE
                stt.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              ORDER BY
                created DESC
            ) AS x
            CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT
                @calc_prevdate := NULL
            ) as vars
          ) AS z
          CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT
              MAX(created) AS latest_date
            FROM(
              SELECT
                sto.created
              FROM
                table_one sto
              WHERE
                sto.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              UNION ALL
              SELECT
                stt.created
              FROM
                table_two stt
              WHERE
                stt.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              ORDER BY
                created DESC
            ) as z
          ) AS y
          WHERE
            diff > rtt.relevant_field_two
        ) as w
      )
        GROUP BY us.rto_id
      ),0
    ) AS field_one,
    IFNULL(
      (
        SELECT
          SUM(tt.field_seven) AS field_three
        FROM
          table_two tt
        WHERE
          tt.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
      AND
      tt.created >= (
        SELECT 
          IF(
            selected_date IS NULL,
            MIN(created),
            selected_date
          )
        FROM (
          SELECT
            IF(
              latest_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL rtt.relevant_field_two DAY),
              CURDATE(),
              MAX(prevdate)
            ) AS selected_date,
            created
          FROM (
            SELECT
              created,
              @calc_prevdate as prevdate,
              DATEDIFF(@calc_prevdate, created) AS diff,
              @calc_prevdate := created
            FROM (
              SELECT
                sto.created
              FROM
                table_one sto
              WHERE
                sto.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              UNION ALL
              SELECT
                stt.created
              FROM
                table_two stt
              WHERE
                stt.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              ORDER BY
                created DESC
            ) AS x
            CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT
                @calc_prevdate := NULL
            ) as vars
          ) AS z
          CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT
              MAX(created) AS latest_date
            FROM(
              SELECT
                sto.created
              FROM
                table_one sto
              WHERE
                sto.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              UNION ALL
              SELECT
                stt.created
              FROM
                table_two stt
              WHERE
                stt.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
              ORDER BY
                created DESC
            ) as z
          ) AS y
          WHERE
            diff > rtt.relevant_field_two
        ) as w
      )
        GROUP BY tt.rto_id
      ), 0
    ) AS field_three,
    IFNULL(
      (
        SELECT
          COUNT(*) AS field_two
        FROM
          table_two tt
        WHERE
          tt.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
        GROUP BY tt.rto_id
      ), 0
    ) AS field_two,
    IFNULL(
      (
        SELECT
          GREATEST(
            IFNULL(MAX(us.created), 0), IFNULL(MAX(tt.created), 0)
          ) AS field_six
        FROM
          table_one us
        LEFT JOIN
          table_two tt ON us.rto_id = tt.rto_id
        WHERE
          us.rto_id = rto.relevant_field_one
        GROUP BY us.rto_id
      ), 0
    ) AS field_six
  FROM
    relevant_table_one rto
  LEFT JOIN
    relevant_table_two rtt ON rto.rtt_id = rtt.id
  WHERE
    rto.rtt_id = ?
  GROUP BY rto.relevant_field_one
) v
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

given that query, I need to access `relevant_table_one.relevant_field_one` and `relevant_table_two.relevant_field_two` from inside the subqueries, but the [restrictions on subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html) dictates that you cant access a parents table in a subquery inside a `FROM`

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you are using a query to find a table name for a query that finds the column name for the main query?

Comment: You can't do this. If you explained what the real problem was, then we might be able t help to fix it.

Comment: @Shadow, technically he could just dump another join in the sub-query. But you are correct, if we were given the real problem we could be of a lot more help.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding , but I don't think so. I need to filter the innermost query based on the columns of the table joined in the outermost query

Comment: alright, give me a few minutes to write up a more complete example

Comment: updated the example with the real problem, does that clear it up at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this (so far I think) by adding `@rfo := relevant_field_one` and `@rft := relevant_field_two` up in the select where they were accessable and then referring to the created variables instead of the columns down in the nested query where relevant.

It's possible I'm just getting false positives but so far the solution appears to be working.